# install plpython in postgresql 8 or 9

Tags: python, postgresql, installation, plpython

i want to install plpython on postgresql to have python trigger

when i restore my DB (my db has some python trigger) this error apears (error message was too big so i paste first lines of it):

```
C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0/bin/pg_restore.exe
   --host localhost
   --port 5432
   --username "postgres"
   --dbname "mfa"
   --verbose
   "%HOMEPATH%/Desktop/EhSAA/MFA/db_schema/mydb.backup"

pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: creating SCHEMA public
pg_restore: creating COMMENT SCHEMA public
pg_restore: creating PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE plpgsql
pg_restore: creating PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE plpythonu
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:

pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 315; 2612 16595
                                  PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE plpythonu postgres

pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query:
ERROR: could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0/lib/plpython.dll":
The specified module could not be found.
```

Command was:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Comment: Format your output properly - otherwise this posting is a disaster

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you need to put `plpython.dll` in `C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0/lib`. I just tried the following commands on my system, and it worked.

```
cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.2\bin
createlang --dbname=MyDb plpythonu -U myuser
```

Checking into my `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.2\lib` reveals that I have `plpython.dll` in there. As your error says, it looks like `plpython.dll` is missing from the lib folder of your postgresql installation.

Comment: my postgres is 9 and when i use above command, i get errors :(

Comment: Remove the leading > on the lines. That was there to show the command prompt. Also, change 8.2 to whatever version your dir is. Lastly, ensure that plpython.dll is actually inside C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\x.x\bin

Comment: Did you make sure that plpython.dll is in the lib folder?

Comment: _Lastly, ensure that plpython.dll is actually inside C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\x.x\bin_ I made an error on this comment above, sorry, it's actually _C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\x.x\lib_.

Comment: i found the solution, all these problems are related to my x64 postgresql and its x86 dll s.  thanks so much for your realtime helping :)

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. I'll make a note of this in case someone else has the same problem.